# How to configure xdebug with WAMP

Tags: wamp, xdebug

I am using wamp 2.0 and trying to install XDebug extension for php. I have followed all steps written here http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_configure_xdebug_with_WAMP
but still its not working.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: My WAMP (3.2.0 ) already have xdebug

Comment: watch video here https://youtu.be/jZBAlGUX9bI

Answer (score 59, accepted):

please follow the instructions at http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

cheers,
Derick

Comment: that is an extremely helpful website

Comment: Have to say... I LOVE the fact here, that Derick - the guy who actually wrote Xdebug, actually answered the question. :)

Comment: Watch that you don't grab the DLL suggested for one system and install it on another system (ie. 32 vs 64 bit) This caused problems for a few days with us...

Comment: normally answers need to include a bit more info and a why to do this, this answer is one of the few that actually may not need more than a link, wow!

Comment: Looks like this is an outdated answer - the link takes one to a wizard which doesn't really provide any additional info, other than asking one to paste phpinfo output in a wndow for analysis.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi after pasting the phpinfo details, the page will display the step-by-step.

Comment: Had to jump in and say thank you from 2024.

Answer (score 11):

If you're just debugging a local session using wampserver 3.0.6 and php 7.0.10 using xdebug, there's *almost* no need to edit your ***php.ini*** manually (more on that later).

You may activate **xdebug.remote_enable** from the tray icon menu. Having done so should yield something like the following output in ***php.ini*** (it's at the absolute end of the file):

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

From there, the only thing you need to specifically add yourself (at least when using the php-debug extension in VS Code) to ***php.ini*** is:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Don't forget to restart wampserver after that. ***If*** you need to connect remotely to another host, you would probably need som variation of (replace 127.0.0.1 with remote IP):

```
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

But that is pretty much outside the scope of my answer since that opens up a whole new can of worms IMHO

Answer (score 5):

Follow instructions on http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php as Derick mentioned, but when configuring xdebug on Wampserver 3.0.0 I also had to add the following code to my php.ini.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = C:\wamp\tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

for php 7 the configuration variables were renamed my final working configuration ended up like this:

```
   xdebug.mode = develop,debug,profile
   xdebug.start_with_request=yes
   xdebug.output_dir =c:/wamp64/tmp
   xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
   xdebug.log=c:/wamp64/logs/xdebug.log
   xdebug.log_level = 10
   xdebug.client_host=localhost
   xdebug.client_port=9000
```

Comment: lifesaver, correct settings for php7, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i'm using wamp server 3.3. in there debugger already installed. we need to do little thing to configure it.
step 1:

> install [xdebug
> helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc)
> extension to browser

step 2:-
**open php.ini** file in both **apache module** and **your-php-version**-FCGI-CLI file.you can access these two files from **wamp tray** in **php section**
in there already **[xdebug]** lines there. under **[xdebug]** in `**both**` files add below lines and save. no need to add any other lines than below

> xdebug.mode=develop,debug
> xdebug.remote_autostart=1
> xdebug.start_with_request=yes

step 3:- install **php debugger extension** in vs code. in debugger section **listen to xdebugger**. in xdebugger 3 default port is **9003**

Comment: after 1 day of searching thats work for me . thanks